# Reset Bitbucket Pipeline BUILD_NUMBER

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-api

I was able to do the set initial and increment `$BUILD_NUMBER` using the [API](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-a-new-value-for-the-pipelines-build-number/) but it seems there is no way to clear or set a value lower than the current build number.

> The request body contains invalid properties - your build number is lower than existing builds in Pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

`$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER` is designed to increment up, and if you do nothing to it, it's the same as your pipeline number. If you want to use a different build number you control... create a new variable and have a step to increment the build number as part of the pipeline. You will be able to edit it at will either in the console or with the API

```
  - step:
      name: Increment Build Number
      image: ellerbrock/alpine-bash-curl-ssl # just image with curl and bash
      script:
        - newVer=$((MY_PERSONAL_BUILD_NUMBER++))
        - a=$MY_PERSONAL_BUILD_NUMBER
        - newBuildValue=$((a++))
        - echo $newBuildValue
        - curl -v -X PUT "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/$ORG_OR_WORKSPACE/$REPO/pipelines_config/variables/\{$UUID_VARIABLE\}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"key\":\"MY_PERSONAL_BUILD_NUMBER\", \"value\":\"$newBuildValue\" }" --user $PIPELINE_APP_PASSWORD
```

If you are using your own Docker Image, add curl and bash.